# Developing LWC in LWR without having to publish from experience builder

Tags: lwr, lightning-web-runtime

LWC development in LWR is seemingly painfully slow having to publish with every code change.

Has anyone found a workaround for this? Using preview in the experience builder has it's limitations, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous role, I just enabled my LWC to be usable as a Lightning Tab, and then created a tab for it. This isn't without limitations (e.g. permissions are different, some features don't work in a DE, etc), so I would still suggest publishing daily or so, but the tradeoff is that you have a tab that you can refresh to instantly see the latest changes.

Comment: I am marking this as the best answer for now. Hopefully, in the future a sandbox can enable a non-cached version so your components are loaded dynamically like in Aura...or something :P